# Campo data não salva no banco de dados Spring e Angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-data

Estou fazendo um pequeno CRUD e na quando eu salvo os dados os campos dataInicio e dataFim não salvam no banco de dados. PS: fiz o debug e as datas estão passando pelo método salvar.

```
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                              <label>* Data de início:</label>
                                <input name="inpDataInicio"  type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="promocao.dataInicial" />
                             </div> 
                               <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                 <label>* Data de fim:</label>
                                 <input name="inpDataFim"  type="date" class="form-control"   ng-model="promocao.dataFinal"/>
                             </div>
```

Controller

```
app.controller("promocaoController", function($scope, $http){

    $scope.promocoes = [];
    $scope.promocao={ }; // binding com o form  



carregarPromocoes = function() {

        //token=localStorage.getItem("userToken");
        //$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;

        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/promocoes'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.promocoes = response.data;


        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });
    }; 

    $scope.salvarPromocoes=function(){
        if($scope.frmPromocao.$valid){
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/promocoes', data:$scope.promocao
        }).then(function(response) {
            // $scope.clientes.push(response.data);
             $("#modalSalvoSucesso").modal("show");
            carregarPromocoes();
            $scope.promocao={};


        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });


        }else{
             $("#modalCampoObrigatorio").modal("show");

        }

    };



    $scope.excluirPromocoes=function(promocao){
        bootbox.confirm({
            message: "Deseja excluir o registro permanentemente ?",
            buttons: {
                cancel: {
                    label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar'
                },
                confirm: {
                    label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Sim'
                }
            },
            callback: function (result) {
                if(result == true){
                    $http({
                        method : 'DELETE',
                        url : 'http://localhost:8080/promocoes/'+promocao.id
                    }).then(function(response) {

                        pos= $scope.promocoes.indexOf(promocao);
                        $scope.promocoes.splice(pos,1);


                    }, function(response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        console.log(response.status);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        }; 

        $scope.alterarPromocoes=function(pro){

            $scope.promocao=angular.copy(pro); 

        };

        $scope.cancelarAlteracaoPromocoes=function(){
            $scope.promocao={};
        };

    carregarPromocoes();

});
```

Controller Java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class PromocaoController {

    @Autowired
    PromocaoService promocaoService;


    //end points


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/promocoes", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Promocao> cadastrarPromocao(@RequestBody Promocao promocao){
        Promocao promocaoCadastrada = promocaoService.cadastrar(promocao);
        return new ResponseEntity<Promocao>(promocaoCadastrada, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/promocoes", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Promocao>> buscarTodasPromocoes(){

        Collection<Promocao> promocaoBuscadas= promocaoService.buscarTodos();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(promocaoBuscadas, HttpStatus.OK);
    } 

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/promocoes/{id}", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Promocao> buscarPromocaoPorId(@PathVariable int id){

        Promocao promocao= promocaoService.buscaPorId(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(promocao, HttpStatus.OK);
    } 


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/promocoes/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Promocao> excluirPromocao(@PathVariable int id){
        Promocao promocaoEncontrada = promocaoService.buscaPorId(id);
        if(promocaoEncontrada == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        promocaoService.excluir(promocaoEncontrada);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/promocoes", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Promocao> alterarPromocao(@RequestBody Promocao promocao){
        Promocao promocaoAlterada = promocaoService.alterar(promocao);
        return new ResponseEntity<Promocao>(promocaoAlterada, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Java

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;




@Entity
public class Promocao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String produto;
    private double preco;
    private String marca;
    private String categoria;
    private String uniMedida;
    private String observacao;

    @Column(name = "dataInicio")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataInicio;

    @Column(name = "dataFim")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataFim;

    private String status;

    @JoinColumn
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    private Usuario usuario;

    private String foto;






    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(String produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }

    public double getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }

    public void setPreco(double preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getUniMedida() {
        return uniMedida;
    }

    public void setUniMedida(String uniMedida) {
        this.uniMedida = uniMedida;
    }

    public String getObservacao() {
        return observacao;
    }

    public void setObservacao(String observacao) {
        this.observacao = observacao;
    }

    public Date getDataInicio() {
        return dataInicio;
    }

    public void setDataInicio(Date dataInicio) {
        this.dataInicio = dataInicio;
    }

    public Date getDataFim() {
        return dataFim;
    }

    public void setDataFim(Date dataFim) {
        this.dataFim = dataFim;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(String foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    } 






}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione a anotação @DateTimeFormat do Spring sobre os campos de datas. Essa anotação vai converter o valor da data que vem como um texto do formulário para um objeto java.util.Date. Exemplo:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
@Column(name = "dataFim")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dataFim;
```

Comment: Fiz da forma que você sugeriu mas continua salvando data como null no banco.

Comment: Então, será que o valor da data realmente está chegando ao lado servidor?  Verificou isso?

Comment: haviam dois problemas: o primeiro era uma declaração equivocada no ng-model , a segunda era a formatação da data, usei o seguinte método:  `app.directive("formatDate", function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
                if (modelValue){
                    return new Date(modelValue);
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
    };
}); `